# How to get values out of IGrouping?

Tags: c#, linq, igrouping

I have applied IGrouping<> over a list - here's what it looks like:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TierRequest,PingtreeNode>> Tiers
{
    get { return ActiveNodes.GroupBy(x => new TierRequest(x.TierID, x.TierTimeout, x.TierMaxRequests)); }
}
```

Later in my code I iterate over Tiers. Its simple to get the key data using the Key element, but how do I get the `IEnumerable<PingtreeNode>` that forms the value part?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Tiers.Select(group => group.Select(element => ...));`

Comment: Ah, stupidly simple, yet too stupidly simple for me to work out, lol

Answer (score 5):

The group itself implements `IEnumerable<T>` and can be iterated over, or used with linq methods.

```
var firstGroup = Tiers.First();

foreach(var item in firstGroup)
{
  item.DoSomething();
}

// or using linq:
firstGroup.Select(item => item.ToString());

// or if you want to iterate over all items at once (kind of unwinds
// the grouping):
var itemNames = Tiers.SelectMany(g => g.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

in foreach you can get values like this

```
foreach(var group in tiers)
{
    TierRequest key = group.Key;
    PingtreeNode[] values = group.ToArray();
}
```